# How should I update database and RecyclerView in Kotlin after every midnight?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I would like to make a simple Habit Tracker app in Kotlin.
I already have a main database where the app stores the habits with dates, and a 'Daily View' where the user can see his habits and check/uncheck them.

My main problem is that I don't know how add new habits with new dates and unchecked checkboxes to the database after every midnight.

Here is the code I wrote:

HabitItem.kt

```
@Entity(tableName = "habititem")
data class HabitItem(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "habitId") @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long? = null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description") var description: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") var date: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "isDone") var isDone: Boolean
) { }
```

HabitListDatabase.kt

```
@Database(entities = [HabitItem::class], version = 1)
abstract class HabitListDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun habitItemDao(): HabitDao

    companion object {
        fun getDatabase(applicationContext: Context): HabitListDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(
                applicationContext,
                HabitListDatabase::class.java,
                "habit-list"
            ).build();
        }
    }
}
```

HabitDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface HabitDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM habititem")
    fun getAll(): List<HabitItem>

    @Insert
    fun insert(shoppingItems: HabitItem): Long

    @Update
    fun update(habitItem: HabitItem)

    @Delete
    fun deleteItem(habitItem: HabitItem)
}
```

HabitAdapter.kt

```
class HabitAdapter(private val listener: HabitItemClickListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HabitAdapter.HabitViewHolder>(){

    private val items = mutableListOf<HabitItem>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = HabitViewHolder(
        ItemHabitListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    )

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    interface HabitItemClickListener {
        fun onItemChanged(item: HabitItem)
        fun itemIsDeleted(item: HabitItem)
    }

    inner class HabitViewHolder(val binding: ItemHabitListBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HabitViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val habitItem = items[position]

        holder.binding.tvName.text = habitItem.name
        holder.binding.tvDescription.text = habitItem.description
        holder.binding.cbIsDone.isChecked = habitItem.isDone

        holder.binding.cbIsDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ buttonView, isChecked ->
            habitItem.isDone = isChecked
            listener.onItemChanged(habitItem)
        }

        holder.binding.ibRemove.setOnClickListener {
            deleteItem(habitItem)
            listener.itemIsDeleted(habitItem)
        }
    }

    fun deleteItem(item: HabitItem) {
        items.remove(item)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun addItem(item: HabitItem) {
        items.add(item)
        notifyItemInserted(items.size - 1)
    }

    fun update(habitItems: List<HabitItem>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(habitItems)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: automatic or manual ?

Comment: @yansam automatic, after midnight I want all of the different habits in the database with new dates

Comment: [workMager](https://developer.android.google.cn/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Comment: Or if you don’t automatically generate notifications for them you can just add them for all missed midnights the next time the UI is opened.